# What does server.error.include-binding-errors=on-param in Spring do?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

What does the following setting in `application.properties` in a Spring application do?

```
server.error.include-binding-errors=on-param
```

I can't find it in the documentation.

The `always` and `never` values are pretty self-explanatory, but I don't understand `on-param`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To begin, what I did is to do a global search on `server.error.include-binding-errors` in the library, which lead me to `spring-configuration-metadata.json`

```
    {
      "name": "server.error.include-binding-errors",
      "type": "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorProperties$IncludeAttribute",
      "description": "When to include \"errors\" attribute.",
      "sourceType": "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorProperties",
      "defaultValue": "never"
    },
```

We see the related attribute is `errors` here, and the value class is `IncludeAttribute`. By checking the documentation in [IncludeAttribute#ON_PARAM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorProperties.IncludeAttribute.html#ON_PARAM)

> public static final ErrorProperties.IncludeAttribute ON_PARAM
> Add error attribute when the appropriate request parameter is not "false".

We know that the `errors` attribute will be added when there is a request parameter that is not "false".

---

If you want something concrete, let's consider the following example:

*Controller*

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping("/dummy")
    public String test(@Valid @RequestBody DummyDTO dummyDTO) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

*DTO*

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class DummyDTO {
    @NotNull(message = "mandatoryText can not be null")
    private String mandatoryText;

    private String canBeNullText;

    public String getMandatoryText() {
        return mandatoryText;
    }

    public void setMandatoryText(String mandatoryText) {
        this.mandatoryText = mandatoryText;
    }

    public String getCanBeNullText() {
        return canBeNullText;
    }

    public void setCanBeNullText(String canBeNullText) {
        this.canBeNullText = canBeNullText;
    }
}
```

Suppose we set
`server.error.include-binding-errors=on-param`

When we run with parameter **errors=false**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"canBeNullText":""}' -X POST http://localhost:8080/dummy?errors=false
```

the result will not include `errors`

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-06-11T13:38:29.868+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/dummy"
}
```

When we run with parameter **errors=true**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"canBeNullText":""}' -X POST http://localhost:8080/dummy?errors=true
```

the result will include `errors` as

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-06-11T13:51:00.649+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [{
            "codes": ["NotNull.dummyDTO.mandatoryText", "NotNull.mandatoryText", "NotNull.java.lang.String", "NotNull"],
            "arguments": [{
                    "codes": ["dummyDTO.mandatoryText", "mandatoryText"],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "mandatoryText",
                    "code": "mandatoryText"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "mandatoryText can not be null",
            "objectName": "dummyDTO",
            "field": "mandatoryText",
            "rejectedValue": null,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotNull"
        }
    ],
    "path": "/dummy"
}
```

References:
Implementation for web reactive
[`DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler#isIncludeBindingErrors`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.5.0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/error/DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler.java#L224)
[`AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler#isBindingErrorsEnabled`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.5.0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/error/AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.java#L214)

Implementation for web servlet
[`BaseErrorController#isIncludeBindingErrors`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.5.0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/BasicErrorController.java#L167)
[`AbstractErrorController#isBindingErrorsEnabled`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.5.0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/AbstractErrorController.java#L85)

Comment: Thanks for the investigation! It's hard for me to interpret what this all implies. Can you explain how `ON_PARAM` works from a user perspective? For example: Can my application set the `"errors"` parameter in the `ServerRequest`? How to do that? Or is the web request which my application receives that includes the `"errors"` parameter?

Comment: @Lii, thank for your comment, please see if my update makes you clear.

Comment: That is a very thorough investigation, thank you! The edits makes it all very clear indeed. :)

Comment: You have the same behaviour with "server.error.include-message: on_param" and ?message=true.
I think it is way better to use it than errors. It will not return all information. Just the message you want. 

For instance, for 404 error, you can use 
`throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "No resource");`
If the endpoint does not exist, spring return "message: "No message available". 

So you can easilly distinguish the 2 cases.