# Any idea why "server.error.include-message" will not display message if set to "on-param" in Spring application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have been able to generate an error message in my response JSON with the application property `server.error.include-message=always`, but my understanding is that I should be to use "on-param" to only display a message if an error is accompanied by a parameter which they all are.

I've tried both a string parameter and a `getMessage()` call and both work with "always," but never with "on-param."

```
Ex. 
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "This is a bad request")
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage())
```

Looking for:

```json
{
    "timestamp":"2023-01-01T12:00:000+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error":"Bad Request",
    "message":"This is a bad request",
    "path":"/projectpath"
}
```

I would rather use "on-param" instead of "always" given the reason it was changed by Spring to default to "never" in the first place, to try to avoid accidentally revealing too much to a user, but does it matter if there is always a parameter accompanying the error anyway?

Ultimately, I haven't been able to find any insight online as to why using "always" works and "on-param" doesn't so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question has been already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922434/what-does-server-error-include-binding-errors-on-param-in-spring-do

Answer (score 0):

When we use `server.error.include-message=on-param`, the param here implies the query parameter "message". So, adding a query parameter with appropriate value  - true or false, false being the default gives the desired result.

For your particular example, you should use /projectpath?message=true instead of /projectpath.